# Statement is not updating data item

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, collections, linq-to-objects

I have this LINQ statement that tries to set the 1st element in the collection of string[].  But it doesn't work.

Below is the LINQ statement.

```
 docSpcItem.Where(x => x.DocID == 2146943)
           .FirstOrDefault()
           .FinishingOptionsDesc[0] = "new value";

public string[] FinishingOptionsDesc
{ 
        get
        {
            if (this._FinishingOptionsDesc != null)
            {
                return (string[])this._FinishingOptionsDesc.ToArray(typeof(string));
            }
            return null;
        }
        set { this._FinishingOptionsDesc = new ArrayList(value); }
}
```

What's wrong with my LINQ statement above?

Comment: And use `FirstOrDefault(x => x.DocID == 2146943)` instead.

Comment: Just to note that LINQ statement is just a (reading-only) "select statement". It is impopssible to set data through it other than through copying selected data into another data structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things.. There are some problems with your get and set. I would just use auto properties like this..

```
public class DocSpcItem
{
    public string[] FinishingOptionsDesc { get; set; }
    public int DocID { get; set; }
}
```

Next for your linq statement, depending on the presence of an item with an id of 2146943 you might be setting a new version of the object rather than the one you intended. This should work..

```
[TestMethod]
public void Linq()
{
    var items = new List<DocSpcItem>();
    //2146943 
    for (var i = 2146930; i <= 2146950; i++)
    {
        items.Add(new DocSpcItem() 
                     {   DocID = i
                         , FinishingOptionsDesc = new string[] 
                              { i.ToString() } 
                     }
                 );
    }

    var item = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.DocID == 2146943);
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.FinishingOptionsDesc = new string[]{"The New Value"};
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DocSpcItem
{
    public string[] FinishingOptionsDesc { get; set; }
    public int DocID { get; set; }
}
```

[image]